# How to use order ID to get order information?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

After placing an order in SoftLayer using its APIs, I have the Order ID.
(The same Order ID that you see when you go to `Account -> Sales -> Orders in the SoftLayer control panel`).

What APIs are there which I can use this Order ID to get the order information including the invoice or billing?  I tried using `SoftLayer_Billing_Order`, `SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice`, `SoftLayer_Billing_Info`, and etc to see if I can use this Order ID and none of them seem to work.

Using SoftLayer APIs, how can I get the order info, invoice info, and maybe billing info if all I have is the Order ID?

Comment: your question is poorly formatted

Comment: the SoftLayer_Billing_Order service contains all the methods that you need,you just need to specify your credentials and the init parameter which is your Order ID. but in your question is not clear why the service did not work for you, please explain

Comment: Nelson, looks like I was not using  proper ID.  I was using the brand master ID and key, but looks like for order info, I have to use the account user's ID and key.  Using brand master's ID/Key kept giving empty list.  I guess that's because brand master cannot order.  But I thought it would have power to view all account info under it, but I guess not.  I will remember to use the account owner's info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Rest request using `filters` and `masks` can help you:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getOrders?objectFilter={   "orders": {     "id": {       "operation": 7907000     }   } }&objectMask=mask[items.billingItem, initialInvoice]

Method: GET
```

Where: `'7907000'` is my orderId.

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Account::getOrders](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getOrders)

Comment: Thank you. it was very helpful.